# Adding content to dijit Dialog

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've looked at quite a few links for people trying to add content / change the template for a Dojo Dialog. [This was the most promising.](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/How-to-extend-dijit-Dialog-td2738779.html)

However, whenever I do something like this:

Dialog declared in HTML:

```
<div class="djDialog" id="dgViewer" data-dojo-type="TemplatedDialog" data-dojo-props="title: 'My Dialog', draggable:false"></div>
```

Dialog Template:

```
<div class="dijitDialog" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="${id}_title">
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="titleBar" class="dijitDialogTitleBar">
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" class="dijitDialogTitle" id="${id}_title"></span>
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeButtonNode" class="dijitDialogCloseIcon" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick: onCancel" title="${buttonCancel}" role="button" tabIndex="-1">
            <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeText" class="closeText" title="${buttonCancel}">x</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- containerNode from original Dialog template -->
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" class="dijitDialogPaneContent">
        <!-- All "custom" content -->
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'" style="height:300px">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">

            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
                <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">Edit</button>
                <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">Status</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End "custom" content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Custom Dialog class:

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dijit/Dialog', 
    'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
    'dojo/text!./dialog_templates/View.html'], 
    function(
        declare, 
        Dialog, 
        _Mixin,
        _template){
    return declare('TemplatedDialog', [Dialog, _Mixin], {    
        templateString : _template,
        constructor : function(){

        }
    })
})
```

In my console (using Chrome) I just see:

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" class="dijitDialogPaneContent" style="width: auto; height: auto; "></div>
```

... and empty node where content *should* be.

So far I haven't found anyone who seems to have successfully extended dijit.Dialog in terms of templates.  Is this possible?

**Edit**

After trying some variations on this template:

```
<div class="dijitDialog" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="${id}_title">
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="titleBar" class="dijitDialogTitleBar">
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" class="dijitDialogTitle" id="${id}_title"></span>
        <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeButtonNode" class="dijitDialogCloseIcon" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick: onCancel" title="${buttonCancel}" role="button" tabIndex="-1">
            <span data-dojo-attach-point="closeText" class="closeText" title="${buttonCancel}">x</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- containerNode from original Dialog template -->
    <div class="dijitDialogPaneContent">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'" style="height:100%;width:100%">
            <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'">
            <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` is being thrown.  This is the stack, if it helps.  I'm using the uncompressed version from the Google CDN to help in debugging.

```
_childElements          dojo.js.uncompressed.js:8341
getStepQueryFunc        dojo.js.uncompressed.js:8597
query                   dojo.js.uncompressed.js:9005
query                   dojo.js.uncompressed.js:5248
_2._checkIfSingleChild  _ContentPaneResizeMixin.js:2
_4._size                Dialog.js:2
_4.show                 Dialog.js:2
```

Removing the `data-dojo-type` and `-props` from the `containerNode` resolves this, but it's still not getting things closer to having a working custom templated Dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason for troubles with doing templating on a contentpane is, that whatever template-contents you put into the domNode referenced with the attach-point **'containerNode'**, you will loose on startup.

If there is no 'href' nor 'content' attributes set, they will simply be set to an empty string, thus leaving the `Dialog.containerNode.innerHTML == ""`

You have no need for deriving from _TemplatedMixin as the Dialog itself is a templated widget. Instead change this to _WidgetsInTemplateMixin to compensate for the BorderContainer layout widgets and your dijit.form contents. Also, your markup within the custom template should be pre-required, so you could go with something like this here:

Change the template from old attachpoint for container to this

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" 
     data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
     data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
```

Then add requirements to your markup widgets in the template **plus** the `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`:

```
define(["dijit/Dialog",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!./dialog_templates/View.html",
    // rest are for rendering example
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dijit/form/Button"
}. ... );
```

Result should ressemble this, keeping your template View.html change in mind:

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dijit/Dialog', 
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!./dialog_templates/View.html",
        // rest are for rendering example
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dijit/form/Button"], 
    function(
        declare, 
        Dialog, 
        _Mixin,
        _template){
    return declare('TemplatedDialog', [Dialog, _Mixin /*careful, widgetsintemplate is tricky*/ ], {    
        templateString : _template
    })
})
```

You can [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/AErEW/1/)

EDIT:

As there is troubles with dialogs containing borderlayouts (its not unheard of anyways) here's a workaround:

```
    _checkIfSingleChild: function() {
        delete this._singleChild;
       domClass.toggle(this.containerNode, this.baseClass + "SingleChild", !!this._singleChild);

    },
    templateString: '....'
```

Im not certain of the consequences, im thinking the borderlayout of yours might start to misbehave if you try to programmatically change its contents and dimensions.. But it will render - at least it does here: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/AErEW/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your response, it helped me rethink the process, but that fiddle is throwing an error in the console.  Seems like adding any sort of `data-dojo-type` causes it.  The `containerNode` as itself removes the error.  Please see update for actual loaded template.

Comment: yes i noticed that actually.. its an issue that occurs when a widget inside the template is to be rendered. I believe it has to do with layout component containing another layout component - but i aint sure.. However, im not the guy with the answer for this.. Thing is, both dialog and borderlayout is racing against each other to figure out which size to produce. Try disabling the contentpaneresizemixin for your dialog and set it a fixed dimension

Comment: I see, thanks for the push in the right direction mschr!  I'll keep at it and post my results here if I find a solution. Cheers!